What is the correct usage of __has_include
If I don't know where I might find the xyzzy header, should I write (e.g.):
#if __has_include("xyzzy")
# include "xyzzy"
#elif __has_include(<xyzzy>)
# include <xyzzy>
#else
# include <something-else>
#endif

Or as I believe is the correct answer should I just write:
#if __has_include("xyzzy")
# include "xyzzy"
#else
# include <something-else>
#endif


As "" and <> looks at different place, both options might make sense. but generally, you know if you want "" or <>, so testing just the one you want seems better.

The difference between #include "some-file" and #include <some-file>" is that the version with quotes is expected to search your project's source code before searching the system include directories searched by the version with <>. Do I understand right that you don't know if the header file is expected in your project's source code or in a system include directory?

One may argue and say that there is no correct usage because if you ever find yourself in need of this feature, it is an indication of your project design being strange and in need of rework. Source code should not depend on header-files, it should depend on the contents of said header files.

__has_include is required to have exactly the same lookup rules as if the content was placed in #include directive. From [cpp.cond]#4 (emphasis mine):

The header or source file identified by the parenthesized preprocessing token sequence in each contained has-include-expression is searched for as if that preprocessing token sequence were the pp-tokens in a #include directive, except that no further macro expansion is performed.
If such a directive would not satisfy the syntactic requirements of a #include directive, the program is ill-formed.
The has-include-expression evaluates to 1 if the search for the source file succeeds, and to 0 if the search fails.

Then we get to difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename". Again from standard [cpp.include]#3 (emphasis mine):

A preprocessing directive of the form
# include " q-char-sequence " new-line

causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the " delimiters.
The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner.
If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
# include < h-char-sequence > new-line

with the identical contained sequence (including > characters, if any) from the original directive.

So yes, both of your attempts should behave exactly the same. Note that there may be a difference if you reverse the lookup and check for <simde> first - the result would be different if your compiler finds a different file by <> and "" lookup.

@DavidPartridge https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
